# How to activate a worksheet in Excel, where the tab name is dynamic

Tags: excel, vba

I need to activate a certain worksheet which name continuously changes therefore cant specify in my code. There is always only one worksheet in this document, is there a way that I can set this tab as a string within knowing the name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are using VBA and as per your question there is only one worksheet in the excel file you can simply use indexing option in your code like below.

```
sheets(1).range
```

Comment: I thought It was that simple but for some reason wasn't working.
 i = 1
Dim ws As String
ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i)

Comment: If you are using ws as string then you can not set we=thisworkbook.sheets(i). You have to add the name of the worksheet to ws like this : - ws = thisworkbook.sheets(i).name